# Mystery spacing below footer

Tags: css

I am working on the following website - http://theadminguy.co.uk/andrew/our-beers/ and have installed a social sharing plugin. Upon doing this, a 20px space has appeared at the bottom of the viewport.

I have used the element inspector and cannot see any margin or padding on anything to make this happen.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question; and don't obfuscate your URLs behind url-shortening services: Stack Overflow is free, you're not paying for your questions at all, and certainly not per-character.

Comment: Hi David, as my suspicions are that this spacing is caused by the plugin, there is no code to paste as it is embedded using a shortcode, and the url-shortening is just incase the client ever googles the temp address and comes up with this thread. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's causing this is some inline styling on an iframe , specifically:

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" id="linksalpha_info_loader"    src="//www.linksalpha.com/social/info_3?v=2&amp;link=http%3A%2F%2Ftheadminguy.co.uk%2Fandrew%2Four-beers%2F"></iframe>
```

if you get thet height styling out of there your problem is solved_

Comment: Have hidden this iframe using #linksalpha_info_loader {display: none} and this has sorted it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hey try this code your footer is not clear:

```
#footer {
    background: url("images/footbg.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
}
```